# mysql count(distinct case when condition1 then field1, field2, field3 end) as result doesn't allow multiple fields in case statement

Tags: mysql, count, case, distinct, conditional-statements

I want to find how many distinct combinations of toy_id, toy_color, and toy_version were purchased by each of: ‘by_an_adult’ and ‘by_a_kid’.

so the result looks like this, in one row, with ‘by_an_adult’ and ‘by_a_kid’ as the field names (column headers)

```
by_an_adult   by_a kid
465           352
```

suppose:

```
colname_1 = toy_id
colname2 = toy_color
colname3 = toy_version 
colname_4 = toy_purchaser


select 
count(distinct case when colname_4=’by_an_adult’ then colname_1, colname_2, colname_3 else null end) as num_distinct_by_an_adult,
count(distinct case when colname_4=‘by_a_kid’ then colname_1, colname_2, colname_3 else null end) as num_distinct_by_a_kid
from 
a_bunch_of_tables
```

but that is disallowed by mysql.  We seem to only allowed one column after the ‘then’ statement

I also tried

```
case when col4=‘by_an_adult’ then count(distinct col1, col2, col3) end as num_by_adult,
case when col4=‘by_a_kid’ then count(distinct col1, col2, col3) end as num_by_kid
```

but that doesn’t seem right, as the num_by_kid value always comes up null.

Also, I just want one row not two, so I don’t want

```
by_an_adult     465
by_a_kid        352
```

Comment: `CASE` is a expresion and return a value. Cant return a list of fields.

Comment: what is `by_an_adult` a field or a value inside another field?

Answer (score 0):

as @JuanCarlosOropeza said in the comment, CASE expects to get a value, not a list of field. Now since all you care about here is getting distinct count, you can just give it a distinct value based on the three columns, for example a concatenation of them:

```
select 
count(distinct case when colname_4=’by_an_adult’ then CONCAT(colname_1, colname_2, colname_3) else null end) as num_distinct_by_an_adult,
count(distinct case when colname_4=‘by_a_kid’ then CONCAT(colname_1, colname_2, colname_3) else null end) as num_distinct_by_a_kid
from 
a_bunch_of_tables
```

Comment: I was thinking on this. Because I dont think he can `COUNT(Distinct field1, field2, field3)` But he say he can and get null?